# Difference between Closure and Full Closure

Tags: lambda, closures

### My question is:

**What's the difference between Closure and "Full Closure"?**

For my understanding a closure can be define as this:

```
var closure = {

    do something here...

}
```

then you can execute the closure in another time is wanted...

And for what i know a full closure is when you can do something like this...

```
func someFunctionOverHere() {

    doing some things here...

    callSomeClosure { 

        return something  // this return in a full closure for what i
            understood is that i can exit the function "someFunctionOverHere" directly from this inner closure, is
            that right? And if so, its the only difference between a closure and a
            full closure? 

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is this "Full Closure" term defined? If it is language specific (or from such a language specific context), make sure to add the appropriate tags.

Comment: I heard about it, not in specific language at all.

Comment: I've never heard of it before and it does not appear to be a common term. Make sure to post references. If you 'heard' it from someone, ask them.